# Stylus selectors doesnt work after - &

Tags: stylus

I want to get something like that

```
.block__overlay--inverted .block__body {}
```

with such structure

```
.block
  &__body
    color blue

  &__overlay
    &--inverted
      & ~/__body
        color red
```

but instead of i have this

```
.block__overlay--inverted ~/__body {}
```

Selectors like `~/`, `../`, `^[0]` doesnt work after `&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/` and `../` can be used only at the start of a selector (that's intended behavior). But `^[0]` works fine at any position, see http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=.block%0A%20%20%26__body%0A%20%20%20%20color%20blue%0A%0A%20%20%26__overlay%0A%20%20%20%20%26--inverted%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%20%5E%5B0%5D__body%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%20red

Comment: Ok, thanks. Unfortunately phpstorm plugin doesnt support these selectors. But supports "~/" selector, though.